# Insertar varios valores en una columna - MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

tengo un problema en MySQL, se me pide que realice una base de datos de un hospital, y se me pide **consultar a los pacientes que tienen mayor cantidad de pagos de medicamentos**. Mi duda es, **como hago para que un paciente tenga uno o mas medicamentos a la hora de insertar los datos en la columna y consultarlos.**

Esto es lo que tengo, y me imprime el costo máximo del medicamento que toma el paciente, pero no se como hacer para que el paciente tenga mas medicamentos y la suma máxima me la imprima.

```
SELECT Pacientes.Nom_Paciente, Medicamentos.Nom_Medicamento, Medicamentos.Costo_Medicamento FROM Pacientes
INNER JOIN Medicamentos ON Pacientes.ID_Medicamento = Medicamentos.ID_Medicamento 
 WHERE Costo_Medicamento = (SELECT MAX(Costo_Medicamento) FROM Medicamentos);
```

De esta manera inserto los valores de los pacientes.

```
INSERT INTO `HOSPITAL`.`PACIENTES` (`ID_Paciente`,`Nom_Paciente`,`Ape_Paciente`,`ID_Medico`,`ID_Especialidades`,`ID_Servicios`,`ID_Medicamento`)
VALUES  ('1','Alicia','Gomez','6','1','2','5');
```

Answer (score 0):

Esto es lo que necesitas? podrías probar la consulta por favor?

```
SELECT
    Pacientes.ID_Paciente,
    SUM(Medicamentos.Costo_Medicamento) as suma_costos_medicamentos
FROM
    Pacientes
    INNER JOIN Medicamentos ON Pacientes.ID_Medicamento = Medicamentos.ID_Medicamento
GROUP BY Pacientes.ID_Paciente
```